# Prove convergence of a Binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = \binom{4n}{3n}^{-1}$ .

We have
 $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{4n}{3n}^{-1} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(3n)! \cdot n!}{(4n)!} $$
Considering the ratio test i get 
$$ \frac{(4n)! \cdot (n+1) \cdot (3\cdot(n+1))!}{(4\cdot(n+1))! \cdot (3n)!}$$

Now im stuck here

Comment: Simplify $\dfrac{(4n)!}{(4n+4)!}$ and $\dfrac{(3n+3)!}{(3n)!}$.

Comment: this sum is a hypergometrical series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have $\frac{(4n)!(n+1)((3n+3)!)}{(4n+4)!(3n)!} = \frac{(n+1)(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)(4n+4)}$. Now, we take the limit as n approaches infinity, which yields $\frac{27}{256}$. Using the ratio test, I would imagine that you can finish from here.

Comment: Hah, silly me wanted to put this as an answer but didn't think about the coefficients and thought the test was inconclusive... :P

Comment: @SimpleArt gets the best of us sometimes :)

Comment: Wow im feeling really ashamed of me now because i forgot that $(3n+3)!$ equals $(3n)! \cdot (3n+1) \cdot (3n+2) \cdot (3n+3) $ ... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

By Stirling's formula,
which is
$n!
\approx cn^{n+1/2}e^{-n}
$
where
$c = \sqrt{2\pi}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{(an)!(bn)!}{((a+b)n)!}
&\approx \dfrac{c(an)^{an+1/2}e^{-an}c(bn)^{bn+1/2}e^{-bn}}{c((a+b)n)^{(a+b)n+1/2}e^{-(a+b)n}}\\
&= \dfrac{c^2a^{an+1/2}b^{bn+1/2}n^{(a+b)n+1}}{c(a+b)^{(a+b)n+1/2}n^{(a+b)n+1/2}}\\
&= \dfrac{ca^{an+1/2}b^{bn+1/2}n^{1/2}}{(a+b)^{(a+b)n+1/2}}\\
&= \dfrac{ca^{an}b^{bn}n^{1/2}a^{1/2}b^{1/2}}{(a+b)^{(a+b)n}(a+b)^{1/2}}\\
&= \dfrac{cn^{1/2}}{u^nv}\\
\text{where}\\
u
&=\dfrac{(a+b)^{a+b}}{a^ab^b}\\
\text{and}\\
v
&=\sqrt{\dfrac{a+b}{ab}}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$u > 1$, this goes to zero like
$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{u^nv}$.

If
$a=1, b=3$,
then
$u 
=\dfrac{4^4}{3^3}
=\dfrac{256}{27}
$
and
$v
=\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}}
=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}
$.